# Posting a comment by signing into LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a question about the possibility of writing a comment or review on a website by having to sign into LinkedIn first. Just like how you can Sign into Twitter and post comments, can you do the same with LinkedIn.

I want to make sure that not just anyone is posting comments on a site - that is, I want to verify that its a legitimate person commenting.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn does support this functionality - it's used by AOL on sites like their Defense page:
http://defense.aol.com/

The tutorials page for LinkedIn includes an example of using LinkedIn for Login and Registration on a site:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/tutorials

Or you can simply use Login with LinkedIn directly (if you don't want to integrate with an existing registration system):
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

Hope this helps!